# Mark first distinct row in data set

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I am trying to mark the first distinct occurence in some excel data. Basically, I have `Products`, which have an `Insertion Date` and a `Price Deviation`.

I managed to get the Max Date of each Product by using `=MAX(IF(A2=$A$2:$A$13;$B$2:$B$13;""))`, as an array formula. Furthermore, I also managed to get the latest deviation amount by using, `=MAX(IF(E2 = $B$2:$B$13; $C$2:$C$13; ""))`.

My idea, was to check for the date and the deviation amount and find the products which have the latest insertion date and the highest deviation amounts on a distinct product level.

However, my `insertion date` and `price deviation` are not an unique identifier.

Here is an example:

[image]

Any suggestion, how to mark only the first occurence of an `insertion date` and `deviation` combination?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this could be done more elegantly:

```
=IF(OR(B2<>E2,C2<>F2),"",IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,E2,$C$2:C2,F2)=1,F2,""))
```